# How to split or slice a list into separate chunks in Slim (Ruby Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'm trying to make the following:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's what I've tried.

```
div
  - @my_list.each_with_index do |element, index|
    - if element % 4 == 0                                 
      ul
    li
      Element
```

Unfortunately, the `li` is created under `div` instead of `ul`, how can I achieve the results?

Comment: Try this: - if (index+1) % 4 == 0 || index ==0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`each_slice()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) :

```
div
  - [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].each_slice(4) do |elems|
    ul
      - elems.each do |e|
        li = e
```

Generate this html:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that doesn't fix the problem.  The `li` will be outside the `ul`.

Comment: well, now it does, sure :P

Comment: @Зелёный, aha, this is the keyword I'm looking for in ruby `.slice()` to solve the chunking. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would split the list into two lists for printing.

eg. `@my_list.take(4)` and `@my_list.drop(4)`

And then pass each list to a partial so they can use the same markup.